# Error while executing node (about firebase), but app works fine, even using firebase (angular-universal)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, firebase, angular-universal

I am using angular-universal to connect angular and node.js, while using firebase as dummy-data. 
The app works using both angular and node (even fetching and saving data in firebase).

While running in angular, there are no errors in the console (both the browser console and ng serve).

While running in node it logs an error in the console, about firebase (even though the app works using firebase).

This is the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: firebase.initializeApp is not a function
    at AppComponent../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.ngOnInit (C:\Users\****\Desktop\****\Fevereiro\projeto\dist\server.js:131902:18)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (C:\Users\*****\Desktop\*****\Fevereiro\projeto\dist\server.js:27407:19)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (C:\Users\*****\Desktop\*****\Fevereiro\projeto\dist\server.js:28671:20)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (C:\Users\*****\Desktop\*****\Fevereiro\projeto\dist\server.js:28633:16)
    at prodCheckAndUpdateNode (C:\Users\*****\Desktop\*****\Fevereiro\projeto\dist\server.js:29174:5)
    at Object.updateDirectives (C:\Users\*****\Desktop\*****\Fevereiro\projeto\dist\server.js:131877:264)
    at Object.updateDirectives (C:\Users\*****\Desktop\*****\Fevereiro\projeto\dist\server.js:28962:72)
    at Object.checkAndUpdateView (C:\Users\*****\Desktop\*****\Fevereiro\projeto\dist\server.js:28615:14)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (C:\Users\*****\Desktop\*****\Fevereiro\projeto\dist\server.js:26996:22)
    at C:\Users\*****\Desktop\*****\Fevereiro\projeto\dist\server.js:23427:63
```

Code of (C:\Users****\Desktop****\Fevereiro\projeto\dist\server.js) that calls the method initializeApp:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var core_1 = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/core */ "@angular/core");
var firebase = __webpack_require__(/*! firebase */ "firebase");
var AppComponent = /** @class */ (function () {
    function AppComponent() {
        this.loadedFeature = 'recipe';
    }
    AppComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {
        firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: "******",
            authDomain: "******",
        });
    };
    AppComponent.prototype.onNavigate = function (feature) {
        this.loadedFeature = feature;
    };
    return AppComponent;
}());
exports.AppComponent = AppComponent;
```

Comment: I had same problem before, I changed it to this import firebase from 'firebase/app'; and it worked.

Comment: Hi dnp1204, should I change that import in the angular call and then build the project again, or in the server.js file (line 3)? Thank your for the help.

Comment: I would do it in your app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you dnp1204, your solution worked, althought I had to use a slight different import => import firebase from '@firebase/app';  => Please submit the answer so i can accept. Thank you

Comment: Good to hear it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem before when I imported from 'firebase'. You should import firebase from 'firebase/app'